# Code format for conversion from page to same page but with new variable

Tags: php, html, forms

I have this form:

```
<form action="<?php echo  $php_self;?>" method="get">
    <input type="submit"   value="go" id="text33" /> 
        <select name="match" id="text33" style="width:100px;">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">1</option>
        </select>:select
</form>
```

This form is in the title page `cup?c=2&match`

I want to program the form so that if you press go .. go to the title page
`cup?c= 2&match=1`

As a function

```
$ cup=$_GET['c'];
$ match=$_GET['match'];
```

Comment: Please make it more clear.

Comment: Just have the action to `action="cup?c=2&match=1`? Using PHP_SELF will just redirect to itself.

Comment: Also, it is wrong, It is not $php_self it is $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; unless you have a variable with the $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; value

Comment: I think I should be like `cup.php?c=2&match` if you are not using any framework or self created methods. 
or try a hidden field for cup value `<input type="hidden" name="c" value="2">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove **action** param from tag **form**:

```
<form method="get">
    <input type="submit" value="go" id="text33" /> 
    <select name="match" id="text33" style="width:100px;">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">1</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Or replace your variable

```
$php_self
```

To

```
$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]
```

Comment: same resulte  cup?match=1

Answer (score 0):

i solve the problem

```html
<form action="cup.php" method="get"><input type="hidden" value="<?php echo "2"; ?>" name="c" /><input  type="submit"   value="go" id="text33" /> <select name="match" id="text33" style="width:100px;"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option></select>:select</form>
```

thank you very much